# Type Mismatch W/Long Data Type

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with the following code:

```
Dim i As Long
   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, deleteSheet As Worksheet
   Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
   Dim myRow
i = .Range("A:E").Find("*Data Set*").Row
   If Not i Is Nothing Then
```

Basically this is returning a type mismatch on i and I am not sure how to resolve it.  I would appreciate any help here..

Comment: Where is your `With` statement? Otherwise `.Range("A:E").Find("*Data Set*").Row` should be `ws.Range("A:E").Find("*Data Set*").Row` (or something similar)

Comment: change ***.Range*** to ***Range***

Comment: `i` can't be `Nothing` - it's a `Long`.  You need to test the `Find` return value against nothing - not the `.Row`.

Comment: Should be `i` be the row number or the cell that you've found via `Range.Find`? You seem to check if it is not nothing on the next line -- which is a check for `objects`, not `longs`.

Comment: Also, `Range.Find` will inherit the settings/parameters from the last time it was used -- so things like match whole/part and case sensitive may be anything, unless you specify them explicitly.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Thanks, this pointed me in the correct direction!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!  Changed a couple lines based on the feedback and got it!

```
If Not .Range("A:E").Find("*Data Set*") Is Nothing Then
    i = .Range("A:E").Find("*Data Set*").Row
```

I had a with above, so that was not the issue, actually.  I ended up re-ordering things and doing the validation before setting the variable so it was not using the row value as @comintern and @chillin suggested.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: This will run `Find` 2 times (which makes it slow). Set the result of `Find` to a variable and then test this variable (to run `Find` only once). Eg. `Set FoundAt = .Range("A:E").Find("*Data Set*")` and then use it for `If Not FoundAt  Is Nothing Then` and `i = FoundAt.Row`